# Business activity monitoring and business analytics relation

Tags: wso2, analytics, activity-monitor, wso2-bam

A simple question, yet I couldn't find much information on the subject. How is business activity monitoring related to business analytics? I always thought business analytics is a subsystem of the activity monitoring systems. But that's only my limited view so I was wondering. In that trail of thought, how are for instance WSO2 BAM and Google Analytics compared to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Initially WSO2 BAM 2.x.x was just a data analytic framework that can process big data offline (as batch processes with Apache Hadoop) which can also receive data and visualize data.

But from BAM 2.4.0 it comprises WSO2 Complex Event Processing features (CEP) that can monitor events real-time, process them and visualize them in a relatively low latency according to [1].

In Google Analytics most analytics and dashboards are available out of the box but with WSO2 BAM you may need to write some hive queries and dashboards to come up with a great solution.

WSO2 BAM is open source (Apache Licences) and you can use it as you wish with great flexibility although it lacks some out of the box features compare to the Google Analytics.

From BAM 2.4.0 it comes with an inbuilt Activity Monitoring feature [2] that is based on the concept of an Activity ID. This can be used out of the box when your business process is properly configured for activity monitoring use case.

[1] https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Realtime+Analytics
[2] https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Activity+Monitoring+Dashboard